# how to scan document to android via network

Tags: android, image-scanner

i got some issue about scan document to android via network.
the main goal is any/most scanner can scan document to android via network, like this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mopria.scan.application .
the test scanner is "HP LaserJet MFP M426fdn".

i try to find some solution from github, and found two: SANE and TWAIN.
but M426fdn is not in support list of SANE, also, port 6566 is off. so i think that's not what i want.

i try TWAIN and found the only example https://github.com/twain/twain-direct-android and run it, but cannot found M426fdn...

last i found http://asprise.com/document-scanner-image-pdf/java-scanning-api-overview.html, but it seems to use UI itself...

can someone tell me next step or some keyword or document?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of apps are you going to implement for Android? Native app or web app?

#### For Native App

I ever implemented a simple demo.

Here is the source code:

https://github.com/dynamsoft-dnt/Wireless-TWAIN-Scan-on-Android

The basic steps:

1. Connect the mobile client app to a PC host app via Socket.
2. When clicking the scan button, the PC host app will scan documents from a connected scanner.
3. Then, the PC host app sends the captured image to the mobile client app.

[image]
<sub>(source: [codepool.biz](https://www.codepool.biz/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/twain_android_client.png))</sub>

For detailed information, please read the article - [Wireless TWAIN Document Scanning on Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20180905044212/https://www.codepool.biz/wireless-twain-document-scanning-on-android.html).

#### For Web App

A hosting service is in charge of scanning documents and sending image data via WebSocket. You can refer to the flow chart:

[image]
<sub>(source: [codepool.biz](https://www.codepool.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/sidecar-solution-workflow.png))</sub>

and the article - [Scanner Sidecar Solution with Raspberry Pi](https://web.archive.org/web/20180916133945/https://www.codepool.biz/scanner-sidecar-solution-raspberry-pi.html).